# Does $ \log(x)^{x^a}$ eventually dominate $x^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, asymptotics

Does $ \log(x)^{x^a}$ eventually dominate $x^k$ for all $a\gt 0$ and for all positive integers $k$?

And if so, how does one prove this?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\log\bigl((\log x)^{x^a}\bigr)&=x^a\log\log x\\
\log(x^k)&=k\log x
\end{align}$$
For all $a,k>0$$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^a\log\log x}{k\log x}=\infty.
$$